# How to remove background gap of text messages CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm building a React Chat app. My background of messages works fine with a short text. The background responsively changes according to text-content.

With longer text, when I scale the browser, there are certain points where the background appears larger than the fit-content. Below are the pictures of the same message.

[No Gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS0lL.png)

[With Gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XOr4.png)

Here is my React code:

```
<div className={`chatMessage ${message.sender._id === state._id && "myMessage"}`}>
    <div className="messageHeader">
        <span className="chatName"> {message.sender.name} </span>

        <span className="timeStamp"> {message.timestamp.substring(0, 10)} </span>
    </div>
    <div className="messageContent">
        <span>{message.message}</span>

        <small className="timeStamp"> {message.timestamp.substring(12, 20)} </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.chatMessage {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 2px 10px 0px 10px;
    max-width: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.myMessage > .messageContent {
    background-color: #dcf8c6 !important;
}


.chatMessage > .messageContent {  
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);  
}

.messageContent {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    padding: 2px 10px 0px 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    right: -5px;
}
```

I believe the max-width property is causing the problem. But I can't figure out how to work around it.

Comment: have you try to set up wifth: fit-content;
?

Comment: @aktoriukas yes, it didn't work.

Comment: It's because the width of the word is larger than the width of the gap; there is no way for it to fit in it, so, it moved into a new line. If you want text to fit into the container no matter what, you can set this property `word-break: break-all` which will break the words to fit into the space.

Comment: @ThetAung you're right. Thank you!